# AnythingSlider: how to restart slideshow

Tags: restart, anythingslider

I'm starting the slideshow in a pop up div by clicking a button using $('#slider2').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(true);

Stopping the slideshow by $('#slider2').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false);

When I click the same button to show again it simply continues from the slideshow that was stopped before. I want the whole slideshow to restart again. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when restarting, do this:

```
$('#slider2').anythingSlider(1); // Reset to first slide
$('#slider2').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(true);
```

Comment: It gives this error: $("#slider2").data("AnythingSlider").anythingSlider is not a function

Comment: @ariel actually slideshow was not stopped by $('#slider2').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false); though it was pointed to first slideshow by $('#slider2').anythingSlider(1); how could be show ? Any idea ?

Comment: ok, i guess this should do (see edit). put your stop code back to where it was, and use this start code.

Comment: here is my settings
$(function(){
 $('#slider2').anythingSlider({
  autoPlay  : false,
  startStopped    : true, // If autoPlay is on, this can force it to start stopped
  width           : 800,   // Override the default CSS width
  height   : 480,
  theme           : 'metallic',    
  delay   :4000,
  buildNavigation : false,
  autoPlayLocked  : false,  // If true, user changing slides will not stop the slideshow
 });
});

Comment: function previewCampaign(show){
 if(show == false){
  $('#slider2').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false);
  $('#slider2').anythingSlider(1);
 }else{
  $('#slider2').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(true);
 }
}

Comment: Here is the doc to read in [detail](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Usage).